# MySQL: How to limit results to max value of another field?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

In this scenario, I am trying to report on the operating_system_version for each distinct computer_id where the report_id for that computer_id is the greatest.

Currently, I am getting the below results:

```
operating_system_version | computer_id | report_id
10.8 | 1 | 10
10.9 | 1 | 20
10.9 | 2 | 11
10.8 | 2 | 21
```

The above is returned by this statement:

```
SELECT operating_systems.operating_system_version,
       reports.computer_id,
       reports.report_id
FROM operating_systems
INNER JOIN reports
    ON operating_systems.report_id = reports.computer_id
```

Instead, would like return the most recent (highest report_id) operating_system_version for each distinct computer_id, for example:

```
operating_system_version | computer_id | report_id
10.9 | 1 | 20
10.8 | 2 | 21
```

I am brand new to SQL .. Appreciate any help.

Comment: This question is very common. Follow the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag for many solutions.

Comment: Ok wow. Found an excellent post as suggested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add a group by statement and a having statement.

The group by would look like

```
group by computer_id
```

The having would look like

```
having report_id= (select max(report_id) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT operating_systems.operating_system_version, 
        reports.computer_id, 
    reports.report_id
FROM operating_systems INNER JOIN reports ON operating_systems.report_id = reports.computer_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM  reports r2 
                    WHERE r2.computer_id = reports.computer_id 
                    AND r2.reports_id > reports.reports_id)
```

Comment: Likely because I'm a n00b, but all I get with this is: "Unknown column 'r2.reports_id' in 'where clause'"

Answer (score 0):

A subquery would lead you to desired end result:

```
SELECT os.operating_system_version,
       r2.computer_id,
       MAX(r2.report_id)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT computer_id
    FROM reports
) r
INNER JOIN operating_systems os
    ON os.report_id = r.computer_id
INNER JOIN reports r2
    ON r2.computer_id = r.computer_id
```

Comment: Unfortunately this returns only one record:
operating_system_version | computer_id | MAX(r2.report_id)
10.8 | 2 | 21

Instead of the needed return of:

10.9 | 1 | 20
10.8 | 2 | 21

which is the highest report_id for each computer_id.

Answer (score 0):

Need to do a better job looking through other posts. This question is answered in an excellent post at: [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)